# How to Create a Canvas in jQuery and Display it in Multiple Areas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Why is it that if I try display the same canvas element in multiple areas in the dom using .html() only the last one will be output. Have a look at the following example, I create a canvas element and store it inside a variable to be output to two dom elements using .html() but the first element is blank. Why is this happening?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var c = $('<canvas />');
    c[0].height = 200;
    c[0].width = 200;
    var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    $('.canvas_one').html(c);
    $('.canvas_two').html(c);
});
```

```css
.canvas_one{
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 10px;
}

.canvas_two{
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas_one"></div>
<div class="canvas_two"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `c` only ever references the same, single, `canvas` instance. Therefore when you include it in the second `html()` call you're effectively *moving* it from its original location to the target.

If you want to create a new `canvas` instance then you can use `clone()` to create it, like this:

```
$('.canvas_two').html(c.clone());
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var c = $('<canvas />');
  c[0].height = 200;
  c[0].width = 200;
  var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();

  $('.canvas_one').html(c);
  $('.canvas_two').html(c.clone());
});
```

```css
.canvas_one {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 10px;
}

.canvas_two {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas_one"></div>
<div class="canvas_two"></div>
```

Comment: Does this only apply to certain elements? because I can create a variable that holds a paragraph tag and it will be output to both elements

Comment: It applies to all elements you create in this way. Do you have an example of how you're working with the `p`?

Comment: var c = '<p>hello</p>'; Would that technically be a string thats why it works?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because that's a string jQuery will automatically create an Element from it every time you try to append. In the case in your question, `c` is an Element already so jQuery re-uses that reference.

Comment: Did the clone function work for you? In my demo it just creates a blank canvas element

Comment: It appears that clone doesn't copy the data in the canvas context. If you want to clone that you need to do it as an image, which isn't ideal. [Reference](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/content-retention-when-cloning-html5-canvas). I'd suggest cloning first then drawing on both canvases at the same time, if possible

Comment: Probably more effort than its worth for my project. But thanks for clearing all this up I'll keep it in mind next time